# LNK2005 with __declspec(dllexport)

Tags: opengl, gpu, lnk2005

I am programming a simple OpenGL 3D application. If I am running the application on a laptop, the performance is terrible since the internal Intel GPU is selected always and not the more powerfull dedicated AMD GPU.

I did read that I have to inlclude this line to force the application to run on the dedicated GPU:

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) DWORD AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance = 0x00000001;
```

However, I get an LNK2005 error that `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance`is already defined in multiple `.obj` files. I don't know how to fix this and I didn't find this variable name in any of the files that I did include in my application.

If it helps: I am using GLFW3 and GLAD for the OpenGL rendering.

Comment: Where exactly did you put this line? Do not put it in a header file.

Comment: "I didn't find this variable name...": though the compiler found it: what you have is a link-time error.

Comment: Solved! Thank you "tkausl". I did put it in a header file, which was the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting the code in the correct place, as suggested in the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you aren't building GLFW with [`GLFW_USE_HYBRID_HPG`](https://github.com/glfw/glfw/blob/3.3.8/docs/compile.dox#L277-L283) defined, which causes GLFW to export `NvOptimusEnablement` & `AmdPowerXpressRequestHighPerformance` itself.